# Porque estou recebendo esses erros: TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code

Tags: python

Encontrei um código github link para código: https://gist.github.com/shinyquagsire23/0d6a5119ee7fb40de2fcfb9088168d63 mas quando tento executar o código recebo essas mensagens:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
atualmente não tenho conhecimento em python, conheço um pouco de php e c#. Por favor se alguém poder me explicar e corrigir esses erros ou se possível rescrever o script em php ou c# pois ficaria mais fácil para me compreender. Desde já agradeço a todos que ajudar, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no encode das strings que deve está em bytes, se estiver usando python3.

Nessas partes

```py
lg_deckey = b"wleldpadptmdkdnt"
lg_enckey = b"qlxnTldlsvntzl!#"
```

```py
def lg_encrypt(string):
    key=lg_enckey
    plain = pad(string)
    iv = b"\x00"*AES.block_size  # <-- bytes aqui
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(plain.encode("utf8"))   # <-- encode aqui
    return base64.b64encode(encrypted_text).replace(b"+", b"m").replace(b"/", b"f")     # <-- encode aqui

def lg_decrypt(string):
    ...

    decrypted_text = cipher.decrypt(crypted)
    return unpad(decrypted_text.decode("utf8"))     # <-- decode aqui
```

O código completo está [aqui](https://gist.github.com/ffernandoalves/3f7ee051cffbfe990bf0cf0db3be28d6).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, testei o código e funcionou, muito obrigado mesmo. no momento estou estudando c#, assim que puder vou estudar python. Muito Obrigado. Vou dá uma estuda básica para ver se consigo rescrever o código em c#. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

```
from Cryptodome.cifra import AES
from Cryptodome.Util import Padding 
"""
O tamanho da chave definida como 32, esta implementando 256 se o tamanho do vetor de  inicialização for igual ao
 tamanho do bloco, que é de 16 bytes.

A chave  inicial e o vetor de inicialização proposto apenas  uma letra (H), recomendavel acrescentar uma chave
mais complexa.
"""

chave = b"H" * 32
"""Chaves AES podem ter o tamanho de 128 bits (16 bytes)
                                     192 bits (24 bytes)
                                     256 bits (32 bytes) """
IV = b"H" * 16 


cifra = AES.new(chave, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
"""objeto recebe  a chave HSC e o  modo que é CBC"""

mensagem = "Linux" # mensagem a ser utilizada

preparadamensagem  = Padding.pad(mensagem.encode(), 16)
"""Mensagem  criptografar passada para função de preenchimento a função de parte.
para garantir mais segurança foi adicionado  o tamanho da mensagem  de 16 bytes  multiplicando
"""

criptografada = cifra.encrypt(preparadamensagem )


print (criptografada)
"""resultado

Independentemente do tamanho do texto, a função 
se encarregará de dividir o texto em blocos onde cada bloco tem 16 bytes.
Pode aumentar o tamanho da mensagem em vez de 16 para 50 ou qualquer tamanho.

"""

decifra = AES.new(chave, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
prontamensagem = decifra.decrypt(criptografada)
semcriptografia= Padding.unpad(prontamensagem, 16)

print(unpaddedcriptografada.decode()) 
"""desfazendo criptografia
  Se a mensagem já esta criptografada com uma chave segura base64 não vai 
  fazer muita diferença.
"""
```